# How to create a data frame for each group in the pandas.groupby function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which has been grouped by 'hour'. I want to use a for loop which loops through each group and creates a data frame for each group. The code I'm using at the moment only creates a data frame for the last group that it iterates through. Any suggestions on how I can get it to work properly?

```
for name, group in data.groupby('hour'):
    d = {'group_' + str(name) : group}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're overwriting your object each time you want this:

```
d = {}
for name, group in data.groupby('hour'):
    d['group_' + str(name)] = group
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, what a stupid mistake. Thanks very much. Works perfectly!